# PHP получить полный путь из относительного

Tags: php

Есть файл, у которого мы знаем путь до корня сервера;

```
/var/www/papka/index.php
```

Есть файлы у которых известны только относительные пути к файлу (выше).

```
 ../../path/files/1.jpg
 img/files/1.jpg
../new/2.png
```

Суть вопроса в чем - нужно зная полный путь от файла index.php, узнать полные пути к корню сервера, для файлов у которых мы знаем только относительные пути, причем расположение файлов может меняться.

То есть на выходе должно быть примерно так:

```
/var/www/over/list/path/files/1.jpg
/var/www/papka/img/files/1.jpg
/var/www/list/new/2.png
```

Тому кто посоветует красивое и универсальное решение, буду кране признателен!

Comment: `realpath()` устроит?

Comment: Нет, не подходит

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.predefined.php  а вот это подходит ?

Comment: Нет, не подходит

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $path_parts = pathinfo('/var/www/papka/index.php');
    $dir = $path_parts['dirname'] + '/';
    var_dump(realpath($dir + '../../path/files/1.jpg'));           
    var_dump(realpath($dir + 'img/files/1.jpg'));           
    var_dump(realpath($dir + '../new/2.png'));
```

Comment: realpath() "не подходит" :)

Comment: @PinkTux Значит это школьная лаба и надо делать самому :).

Comment: Нет братцы не подходит, realpath() по разному работает на Windows и Linux серверах. На Линуксе все пучком, но на Вндовых машинах идет обратный слэш и буква диска в довесок. Пришлось изобретать велосипед с циклом и разбивкой на массивы, некрасиво но работает корректно. Да и это не лабораторная работа, из школьного возраста давно уже вышел.

Comment: @PegasBY Я вас обрадую у вас не правильное решение. 1. Если вам Нада кросс платформенность то для винды надо хранить так как возвращает. 2. Если это веб приложение то иметь 2 сервера на разных платформах Win/Linux еще глупее. 3. Кто мешает не масивами морочить себе голову а просто потом str_replace прогнать.

Comment: Я обдумывал и пробовал ваш вариант, но он работает некорректно (тестировал), а по вопросу почему на разных платформах, так это не от меня зависит, но мое дело чтобы при любых условиях, выдавался гарантированный результат.